# How to generate C#-friendly, .Net 4.0 compatible types using F# 3.0 type providers

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I want to generate "strong" types based on "weakly" typed data sources, using the F# 3.0 type provider mechanism. The generated types must be accessible from C# clients in an environment where only .Net 4.0 is installed, but not .Net 4.5. If .Net 4.0 compatibility is not possible, we cannot use type providers in our current large-scale ERP project.

So far, I have succeeded in creating MyGeneratedTypes.dll by following the [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on msdn (section "Providing Generated Types"), using the `ProvidedTypeDefinition` from "ProvidedTypes-0.2.fs", which is part of the F# 3.0 sample pack. (In order for it to work, I had to remove the line "`File.Delete`..." from the "`ProvidedTypeDefinition.ConvertToGenerated`..." method).

MyGeneratedTypes.dll has runtime version v4.0.30319, which is OK (the runtime of .Net 4.0). I can add a reference to MyGeneratedTypes.dll in a C#/.Net 4.0 application, and IntelliSense shows the types and members as expected. However, when I try to compile, the C# compiler fails and produces 'warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyGeneratedTypes" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.3.0.0" than the version "4.0.0.0" in the current target framework.'

A look at IL Spy confirms that MyGeneratedTypes.dll indeed contains a reference to FSharp.Core 4.3, eventhough this reference is completely unnecessary. So far, I have found no way to prevent the F# compiler from putting this reference into the generated assembly. (Among other things, I have created a pure .Net 4.0 assembly in C# and passed it to the constructor of `ProvidedTypeDefinition`, but this has no influence).

Does anybody know a) how to get rid of the reference, or b) if this is only an F# 3.0 release candidate problem, which will be solved in the final release.

**Edit**

The conversation with @Brian has resulted in the following "partial" solution to the problem: You *can* compile a "pure C#/.Net 4.0" client referencing a library with F# 3.0 generated types, but only by calling the .Net 4.0 C# compiler (*csc*) directly *from the command line*. It does not work when compiling in VS 2010 or via MSBuild command line. I suspect this is caused by the following behavior:

1. MyGeneratedTypes.dll is generated in VS 2012 with the F# type provider mechanism.
2. During generation, a reference to FSharp.Core 4.3 is automatically inserted (even if not needed), without specifying "SpecificVersion:true" in the metadata for the dependency.
3. A C# client in VS 2010 on a ".Net 4.5-free" system references MyGeneratedTypes.dll.
4. When the C# client is compiled, MSBuild discovers the indirect reference to FSharp.Core 4.3 inside MyGeneratedTypes.dll.
5. Because the indirect reference exists with "SpecificVersion:false", MSBuild emits the warning *MSB3257* and refuses to pass the direct reference /r:"MyGeneratedTypes.dll" to the C# compiler (csc). (Note: MSBuild warnings cannot be suppressed in any way.)
6. The C# compiler (csc) is called by MSBuild, without /r:"MyGeneratedTypes.dll". Therefore, it cannot compile, and emits compiler error CS0246: "The type or namespace name 'MyGeneratedTypes' could not be found (...)".

As far as I can tell, we're stuck with this problem unless the F# type provider mechanism is modified either a) to exclude the ref to FSharp.Core 4.3 when it is not needed in a generated assembly, or b) to include the ref with the metadata "`SpecificVersion:true`".

Comment: I do not have an answer, but I'm curious - why do you want to use F# type providers if you're going to use the library from C#? Are you planning to move to F# in the future? Because if not, using CodeDOM or Roslyn might be easier way to solve the problem. I think most of the value of type providers comes when you consume them from F#...

Comment: @Tomas We are using F# as an additional language in the non-UI parts of a solution who consists mostly of many C# projects. I was hoping that type providers offer a simplified way of creating a CLI type generator (by using _F# quotations_ and the streamlined API of _ProvidedTypeDefinition_). So far, I like what I see, but it does not compile with C# (yet?). For years, we have been using a self-made generator who produces C# source code files, which is a hassle to maintain. I will look into CodeDom and Roslyn  if type providers do not work -- thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a reference to FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 in the C# project (or ignore the warning).  Despite the weird numbering convention, FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 does not depend on anything in .Net 4.5, it only depends on .Net 4.0.

Comment: I have already tried this. Either way, the C# compiler gives two errors saying it does not find the namespace and the type in the generated assembly, although both are perfectly visible via C# IntelliSense (There is no problem at C# coding time, only at C# compile time). The only other message from the C# compiler is the "internal F# reference" warning, which is harmless according to your answer. In IL Spy, the assembly looks normal except for the F# reference. If the internal F# reference is not the root cause of the problem, I don't know what else might be...

Comment: Ok, it would be helpful to share the actual compiler errors you're getting.  So you're saying ildasm/ilspy see that these public types appear in the F# assembly, but for some reason the C# compiler does not 'see' them, even though the assembly is reference with a '/r' on the csc.exe command-line?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. The C#/.Net 4.0 client works fine on Windows 8 where .Net 4.5 exists. However, it does not work on Windows 7 where only .Net 4.0 exists. Here, the C# compiler issues two messages: 1) 'error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyGeneratedTypes' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)', and 2) the warning as mentioned in the question. What's strange is that within VS 2010 on Windows 7, C# IntelliSense recognizes the type, and no problems are reported by the C# IDE or ReSharper. It just does not compile.

Comment: B.t.w., when I add the 'FSharp.Core 4.3' reference in the 'C#/.Net 4.0' project on Windows 7 (where .Net 4.5 is not installed), a yellow exclamation mark appears next to the reference in the VS 2010 IDE, indicating some kind of conflict.

Comment: Furthermore, adding binding redirections from the old FSharp.core versions to FSharp.core 4.3 in the C# client's configuration file does not help, either.

Comment: I have found a "half" solution to the problem: As you correctly predicted, the C# compiler, _when run from the command line_, can successfully build a C# client who uses an F# library with generated types. Compilation succceeds even on a platform where only .Net 4.0 is installed. In order to run the client, FSharp.core.dll (v 4.3) must be present, even if it is not used at all by the generated types. It's only a "half" solution, because compilation is _not_ possible _from within VS 2010_. We can't ask all our developers to stop compiling in VS 2010...

Comment: What command line does VS2010 give (output window)?  How does it differ from what works?

Comment: VS 2010 output window: See the 3rd comment to your answer above. What works: compiling "manually" via command line:

Comment: csc MyGeneratedTypesCSharpClient.cs /r:MyGeneratedTypes.dll

Comment: It differs from what works in that VS 2010 outputs an error message and a warning, whereas the command line correctly creates MyGeneratedTypesCSharpClient.exe without further problems.

Comment: But you're saying VS2010 generates the same command line, and fails?  My guess would be 2010 has the wrong command line arguments (which is why it fails), but perhaps there is a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful hints. I have sent you a repro zip file by mail in case you want to dig deeper. For the moment, I accept the fact that it only seems to work via command line.