# f# .net framework 4.0 and typeproviders

Tags: f#, type-providers, websharper

Well my third question on stack and again about same topic :-)

So I decided to upload my application built in websharper on appharbor but of course there is a problem. After trying to use visual studio 2012 and .net framework 4.5 and getting strange errors which were unsolvable for me (I didn't want to google all day) I decided to use vstudio 2010 and .NET framework 4.0. 
Everything went fine (I copied typeproviders.dll) but there is compile error on appharbore. Here is a log. http://pastebin.com/r9MtegHH and if you are too lazy to click here is a problem line:

```
D:\temp\ovuxcbrh.4p1\input\borkfork\borkfork\Website\borkData.fs(19,102): error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '=' in type arguments. Expected ',', '>' or other token. [D:\temp\ovuxcbrh.4p1\input\borkfork\borkfork\Website\Website.fsproj]
```

It works fine on my vstudio 2010. 
And line of code is:

```
    type  internal dbSchema = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = @"Data Source=IRON;Initial Catalog=borkdorkfork;Integrated Security=True">
```

Maybe there is a problem because I didn't yet configure database overthere but it looks like something else. Well I am going to configure db overthere and see.

Answer (score 6):

Code that uses type providers will run on .NET 4.0, providing that code has been compiled with the F# 3.0 compiler (targeting .NET 4.0) and references FSharp.Core and FSharp.Data.TypeProviders 4.3.0.0 with Copy Local set to True.

The problem in this case is that AppHarbor builds your code for you. Since they haven't updated to .NET 4.5 yet, your code is being compiled with the F# 2.0 compiler, which doesn't understand type providers.

If AppHarbor had a way for you to compile your own binaries and deploy those, that would work.

Edit:

I think this compiles for you on VS 2010 because .NET 4.5 is an in-place replacement for .NET 4.0. It must be replacing the F# compiler that VS 2010 uses, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Type providers **requires** .NET 4.5. The error is the standard syntax error, because it expects you to close the triangle brackets, which it thinks are not type provider parameters, but **generic parameters** - the only use for triangle brackets in F# 2.0.

Comment: I don't understood what you mean by requering .net 3.5. App is working perfectly on localhost and .net framwork >= 4.0. On 3.5 I get millions of errors. Can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: Type providers require the F# 3.0 compiler, and .NET 4.0 or above. They do not require .NET 4.5. A program compiled with the F# 3.0 compiler, but targeting the .NET 4.0 framework, will run quite happily on a machine that has never seen .NET 4.5. The problem in this case is that AppHarbor compiles your code, and they're doing it with the F# 2.0 compiler.

Comment: Here's a reference, aside from the fact that I just did this last week and it worked fine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11125771/24380

Comment: @JoelMueller Indeed, you are correct - FSharp.Core 4.3 does not require .NET 4.5 (I thought I remembered such a limitation from the Beta, but seems I was wrong). borkdorfork - Did you remember to use FSharp.Core 4.3, and redirect to it if necessary?

Comment: I did actually played with fsharp.core version. I added it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v4.0  to bin\Debug version and added reference to it but it seems I don't know how to tell vstudio which version to use. Can you please tell me how to tell vstudio which version to use.

Comment: Edit: I actually moved project to vstudio 2010 because appharbor seems to use .net framework 4.0 and f# 2.0 so if I manage to add f# 3.0 to vstudio it will probably work there. It's actually quit weird because build solution comes with that error, but hitting f5 ignores it.